# Javascript create Timestamp from format

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

I have a string of dd.mm.yy (e.g. 31.12.1990).

I have tried string.getTime() without success. 
well I guess I have to tell Javascript in which format the given string is, but How?

So, how do I convert this string to a unix timestamp in Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+date+javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to correctly read this string as a valid datetime object and then you can read it as the way you want :

```
 from = ("31.12.1990").split(".");
 myDate = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
 myDate.getTime() / 1000;
```